# Как в php отделить номер от текста

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Привествую,есть код:

```
<?php
    $file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
       $line = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $line);

        echo "<pre>\n" . $line . "\n</pre>\n";

    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    ?>
и есть файл со строками текста и цифрами например :viber +380633333303 работаем до 15 00 .. как выбрать только слово viber и номер телефона, а не получить в итоге.... +3806333333031500 одной строкой ?

    <?php
    $file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
    preg_match('~\pL+\s\+\d+~', $file_handle, $line);

        var_dump($line);

    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    ?>
file.txt
  "biography": "Ароматы для дома и автомобиля \n+380638594585 \nDirect/Viber/What's App \nДоставка по всей Украине!!!",
          "biography": "Большой выбор купальников\n#отзывыgirlspowershop\n+380634258077;+380633343919  \ndirect|viber|whatsap\nДоставка по всей Украине НП\n#купальникиукраина",
+380955513649 Nina",
+380977014922",
+380977370300\nhttps://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100017212",
```

Если нужно оставьте, реквизиты я пополню счет или как-нибудь вас отблагодарю за помощь!

Comment: Приведите больше примеров строк

Answer (score 3):

> *как выбрать только слово viber и номер телефона?*

Для текущей строки подойдёт следующее решение:

```
$str = ':viber +380633333303 работаем до 15 00 ';

preg_match('~\pL+\s\+\d+~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'viber +380633333303' (length=19)
```

---

Можно собрать массив всех номеров:

```
$fname = 'file.txt';

$array = file_exists($fname) ? file($fname) : [];
$numbers = [];

if (!empty($array)) {
    foreach ($array as $str) {
        if (preg_match_all('~\+\d+~', $str, $arr)) {
            foreach ($arr[0] as $number) {
                $numbers[] = $number;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($numbers);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '+380638594585' (length=13)
  1 => string '+380634258077' (length=13)
  2 => string '+380633343919' (length=13)
  3 => string '+380955513649' (length=13)
  4 => string '+380977014922' (length=13)
  5 => string '+380977370300' (length=13)
```

Comment: так, а как это применить построчно in txt file?

Comment: @CruzeFan вместо переменной $str из моего примера, подставьте переменную $line. Ну и код пропишите в теле цикла.

Comment: Я пробовал, тогда выдает весь текст из файла, регулярка не срабатывает...

Comment: @CruzeFan напишите в вашем вопросе _(используя ссылку "править")_ несколько строк из текстового файла.

Comment: Готово! Правку сделал

Comment: как и просили приложил код и пару строк файла..

Comment: @CruzeFan но у вас ведь в текст.файле не такой формат строк, который заявлен в вашем вопросе, и разумеется регулярка не находит совпадений. Так как формат строки изменился, то теперь нужно уточнить, что же именно вы хотите получить из конкретно вот этих строк: `"biography": "Ароматы для дома и автомобиля \n+380638594585 \nDirect/Viber/What's App \nДоставка по всей Украине!!!",
"biography": "Большой выбор купальников\n#отзывыgirlspowershop\n+380634258077;+380633343919  \ndirect|viber|whatsap\nДоставка по всей Украине НП\n#купальникиукраина",` ?

Comment: Мне нужна фраза viber и номера по строчно, а сейчсас если например телефона 2 или ещё какие либо цифры, то они сливаются в одну строку, я про свой 1-й пример.

Comment: @CruzeFan иначе говоря, вам нужно просто получить из текст файла все телефонные номера? Или нужно получить только те номера, в строке с которыми есть слово `viber` слева или справа от номера?

Comment: Желательно, номера по строчно чтоб они не сливались если их 2-х 2, но если так не получается то номера после слова viber исключая там всякие мы работаем до 15 00 и тд...

Comment: @CruzeFan я добавил код в свой ответ.

Comment: Я сейчас протестирую код спасибо, Как я могу отблагодарить ?

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, но вопрос как можно убрать отовсюду надпись построчного array?      echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>'; немного не то, я новичок в общем поэтому каюсь.